# Google Universal Analytics onClick

Tags: analytics, universal

Looking for some pointers on introducing UA into our website and not sure how to convert the following code extract ...

```
    [button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button"
    onclick="window.location='https://www.jjjoneshomes.com/account'"]
```

... which already has the **onClick** ref into what the UA OnClick Event Tracking is asking for?

Any advice appreciated, an example greatly!

Thanks, Walts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This resource](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) may help you with what you are asking.

UA event tracking normally looks something like this (assuming you use jQuery):

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', $(this).attr('href'));">Click here</a>
```

If you follow the guide above, make sure you don't copy and paste it exactly as it is as there are some errors with the single quote types - they need to be straight quotes, not angled.

Comment: Thanks for that Nyuen, that's got me on the right track! ... Walts

Comment: Here's an example of two onClick events for one link ...

[button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button"
    onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click'); window.location='https://www.jjjoneshomes.com/account'"]

... so the Google UA triggers first before the second onClick event happens! :o] ... Walts